# Echo outside of if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

Here is my code

```
if ($follower_username == $user){

echo $followed_username.",";

};
```

When this runs it echos name,name2,name3,name4

however when I did this

```
if ($follower_username == $user){

$names = $followed_username.",";
};

echo $name`;
```

it only outputs name4,

What is causing it to only pull the last name?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have a closing brace but no opening brace? Why do you put a semicolon after your closing brace?

Comment: That code will definitely not execute, you've got an unmatched `)` and `}` in there. Please post the entirety of the code

Comment: I think you have one `)` too many in your code. try deleting that.

Comment: That was an accident. I wrote it in the editor wrong but its now fixed

Comment: well for one thing you are echoing `$name` not `$names`

Comment: The if statement was within a while statement. Sorry for the confusion this code is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ($follower_username == $user) {
  $names .= $followed_username;
}
echo $names;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
//outside your loop:
$names = '';

while(){
    //...code

   if ($follower_username == $user){

   $names .= $followed_username.",";
   };

   echo $names;
}
```